# Aligning a read more link at the bottom of a container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have the following bootstrap code with two columns as shown below. I would like to have the read more link at the bottom, aligned right. See image.

[image]

```html
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <section class="section mt-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
              <img alt="Web Studio" class="img-fluid" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solodev/vertically-centering/master/images/vc-img-1.jpg" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 ml-auto d-flex align-items-center mt-4 mt-md-0">
            <div>
              <h2>Module Studio</h2>
              <p class="margin-top-s">Whether you&rsquo;re a full stack web developer, content author, or business professional &ndash; Solodev gives you the power to build, customize, and manage modules to boost your website.</p>
           <a href="#" class="primary-cta">Read More</a>
           </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap 5 you can do it in this way:

Add `position-relative` in your col, as said by previous answer of Saeed Shamloo:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 ml-auto d-flex align-items-center mt-4 mt-md-0 position-relative">
```

And in the link class add `position-absolute bottom-0 end-0` like this:

```
<a href="#" class="primary-cta position-absolute bottom-0 end-0">Read More</a>
```

In this way you do not have to use external CSS code. You can find more information about bootstrap 5 position classes [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/position/).

So finally it will look like this:

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <section class="section mt-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
              <img alt="Web Studio" class="img-fluid" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solodev/vertically-centering/master/images/vc-img-1.jpg" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 ml-auto d-flex align-items-center mt-4 mt-md-0 position-relative">
            <div>
              <h2>Module Studio</h2>
              <p class="margin-top-s">Whether you&rsquo;re a full stack web developer, content author, or business professional &ndash; Solodev gives you the power to build, customize, and manage modules to boost your website.</p>
           <a href="#" class="primary-cta position-absolute bottom-0 end-0">Read More</a>
           </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the parent element `position: relative` you can use `position: absolute` on child elements to position them within the parent element. This example should place the link one font-width away from the bottom right corner of 'container-fluid'.

```
.container-fluid { 
    position: relative;
}

.primary-cta {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    bottom: 1em;
}
```

For more info, here's a [breakdown of CSS Positioning from CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/#:%7E:text=To%20make%20the%20child%20element%20positioned%20absolutely%20from%20its%20parent%20element%20we%20need%20to%20set%20this%20on%20the%20parent%20element%20itself%3A). The link opens to the section on Parent --> Child positioning.

Comment: Custom CSS isn't needed for this. Bootstrap provides classes that do all of what you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding `position-relative` to your `col` and `position-abosolute bottom-0 end-0` to your link, like this:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <section class="section mt-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div>
            <img alt="Web Studio" class="img-fluid" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solodev/vertically-centering/master/images/vc-img-1.jpg" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 ml-auto d-flex align-items-center mt-4 mt-md-0 position-relative">
          <div>
            <h2>Module Studio</h2>
            <p class="margin-top-s">Whether you&rsquo;re a full stack web developer, content author, or business professional &ndash; Solodev gives you the power to build, customize, and manage modules to boost your website.</p>
         <a href="#" class="primary-cta position-absolute bottom-0 end-0">Read More</a>
         </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  </div>
```